# Is it possible to use OLEDB to read text from an excel file that contains images?

Tags: c#, excel

I can currently read excel files that contain only text using the OLEDB approach. However, I now need to read files that contain images. I still only require the text/numeric values from the file. I receive an error when opening the OleDbConnection.

So the connection string I am using is the following:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=filename.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;
```

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'External table is not in the expected format.'

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(GetSQLCommandString(conn, sheetName), conn))
        {
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }
        }
 }

 return dt.AsEnumerable()
     .Select(r => new Row(r));
```

So it fails with that error, but once I remove the images it works as expected.

Should I be looking to solutions such as *OPEN XML*, or is there a way I can alter my OleDb approach to work?

Comment: what is your "sql" command string?

Comment: It's a `SELECT * FROM [SHEET]` command, but I've not gotten to that point yet due to the `conn.Open();` exception.

Comment: I don't really know for sure, but you might try selecting exactly what you want instead of `*`.